# How to fetch document with filtered nested document using Mongo query?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is my `organization` collection.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2e"),
    "name" : "ClassA",
    "orgMembers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2f"),
            "userId" : "Ben",
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2f"),
            "userId" : "Anton",
        }
    ],
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2e"),
    "name" : "ClassA",
    "orgMembers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2f"),
            "userId" : "Ben",
        }
    ],
}]
```

Each document has properties like `_id`, `name`, `orgMembers` which represent document information.
And `orgMembers` is the Array of Members `(_id, userId)` who belongs to organization.

In this `collection`, I want to fetch the organizations which includes orgMember with `Anton` as `userId` and as well `orgMembers` of fetched organization document should only contain `Anton` as a orgMember.

Expected Result is likewise

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2e"),
    "name" : "ClassA",
    "orgMembers" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2f"),
            "userId" : "Anton",
        }
    ],
}]
```

Here `ClassA` organization has two orgMembers but need to be filtered matching with `userId`.

I have tried with

```
documentModel.find({ 'orgMembers.userId': 'Anton' })
```

But within this query, I get the result like this.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2e"),
    "name" : "ClassA",
    "orgMembers" : [ 
        // should be omitted 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2f"),
            "userId" : "Ben",
        },

        // should be contained
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5fd5fc1b9f117029b5233b2f"),
            "userId" : "Anton",
        }
    ],
}]
```

For expected result, orgMember with `userId: Ben` should be omitted.

How can I get my expected result with mongo query?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will be worked on your side

```
db.collection.find({
  "orgMembers.userId": "Anton"
},
{
  orgMembers: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      userId: "Anton"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I've tried your solution. https://mongoplayground.net/p/0Kwiku7o_Av
But I didn't get the expected result.

Comment: @AdelinIonut There was a little bit confusing for your question. I've updated the query now.

Comment: hi @KevinLi, you query doesn't work fine for me. If I add another property to orgMember, for example `{ 'userId': 'Anton', 'gender': 'man' }`, it should fetch all properties but in your query, it only fetch  `{ 'userId': 'Anton' }`.
And as well, I need to get all other properties for that `organization` but result excludes other properties of the `organization`.
Can you take a look again the mongoplayground?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i quite got your requirement:

but try this if it works

```
db.collection.find({
  "orgMembers.userId": {
    $regex: "Anton",
    $options: "i"
  }
},
{
  name: 1,
  "orgMembers.$": 1
})
```

this is to return only the `userId` you are looking for in `orgMembers`.if there are more `orgmembers` they will not be part of output